# Heroku deploy notworking

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am having problems with my initial app deployment on Heroku. I've been through both the info in the dev center and Getting Started with Node.js on Heroku. While typing 'heroku open' within the dist directory I get a page that pops up in my browser with the message: Heroku | Welcome to your new app    Refer to the documentation if you need help deploying.

Why isn't my site popping up?

Comment: 1) Have you deployed your app to Heroku? 2) Have you [added a Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#define-a-procfile) to your app?

Comment: Yes to both. I couldn't get as far as I did without this. I followed the aforementioned tutorials in detail. Additional note, I'm using Angular-Fullstack: https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack